# Java : Can I use the thread created on an instance of one class in another class?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to use the the thread created on (say) instance x of class A in another class B. 
I've stated my problems in better way in the form of comments below.

I have something like this:

```
Class A implements Runnable{
  public static int num;

  public void setNum(int i) { num = i; }

  public int getNum() { return num; }

  public void run(){
     while(true){} //I want to keep this thread running continuously
  }
}

Class B{
 A a;

 //I will call this method in class C to use the same instance of class A 
 public A getInstanceOfA() { return a; } 

 public static void main(String[] args){
   a = new A();
   Thread t = new Thread(a);
   t.start();

   a.setNum(5);
   System.out.println(a.getNum()); //getting output as 5. Okay as Expected. 
  }
 }

 class C{
  A a;
  public static void main(String[] args){
   a = getInstanceOfA();

   System.out.println(a.getNum()); 
   //Here I'm getting output 0 not 5 why? As Thread created on instance a is 
   //already running, and also I am using the same instance of class A 
   //so I should get the updated value 5, but getting 0. Why it is re-initializing num?

  }
 }
```

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: You have 2 main methods? Are you saying you want an object to be shared across application instances?

Comment: `You have 2 main methods` exactly my point which one are you running?

Comment: Are you sure that you are ready for multi-threading?

Comment: Well, I want to run main method of both B and C.

Comment: You can run one after another but not both of them simultaneously.

Comment: @Winn : You can run only one main method at a time. If you are running main method of C, you can't run main method of B

Comment: What I want actually is the updated value of variable num everywhere across my appication.

Comment: Okay, if I run one after another won't I get the updated value of num? I was thinking that since the thread t (on instance a of A) is continuously running so I should get the updated value of num if I use the same instance a of A in another class. Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: Is this application only these classes long or does it have more classes ?

Comment: Yes Winn, it is continuously running until and unless you call another method with a main method. It shuts down B and runs C once you call the main method of C.

Comment: Ya It has other classes also. Assume that all these classes updates the num value and also use the updated value.

Comment: Can't I use thread t (created on instance a of A) in class C as well so that I will get updated results (because the context will be same so are the values).

Comment: @Winn: It’s not understandable why you think you need to start a thread at all. If you change the value of a field of an instance, *of course* subsequent reads of the same field of the same instance will return the changed value. Why on earth do you think you need multiple threads in this situation?

Comment: @Winn: Just to clarify: if you are starting multiple JVMs, they always have different instances and starting threads does not change anything about it.

Comment: @Holger: I have two main() methods here(in class B and C). And my requirement is to run both. So how shall I get the updated value of num in class C? I tried without thread too, but I'm not getting the expected results. Thats why I though I should keep the thread running continuously on one instance and then use the same instance to get the updated results in other classes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I am not giving you the exact code but you should do it something like this.

Class B{
 A a;


public B(){
initialize();

}


 //I will call this method in class C to use the same instance of class A 
 public A getInstanceOfA() { return a; } 

// this method should not be main
 public void initialize{
   a = new A();
   Thread t = new Thread(a);
   t.start();

   a.setNum(5);
   System.out.println(a.getNum()); //getting output as 5. Okay as Expected. 
  }
 }

 class C{
  A a;
  public static void main(String[] args){

   B b = new B();
   a = b.getInstanceOfA();

   System.out.println(a.getNum()); 
   //Here I'm getting output 0 not 5 why? As Thread created on instance a is 
   //already running, and also I am using the same instance of class A 
   //so I should get the updated value 5, but getting 0. Why it is re-initializing num?

  }
 }
```

You can also use Singleton

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: But my requirement is that I should be able to run the main() methods of both B and C. Well, If I use main() in both B and C, then will the main() thread create a separate context everytime for B and C, and thats the reason why I am not getting updated value of num? Am I correct? Please correct me.

Comment: If you think that it is the answer, mark it as such.
I am quoting from Stack Overflow only

Java programs have SINGLE point of entry and that is through the main method. Therefore in a single project only one class should have the main method and when compiler will look for that when you run it.
If you run one main after another , there is no relation between them. Yes they are separate contexts and the previous one has been erased.

Comment: Well fine, Thanks a lot. I need to change my requirement.